# Удалить картинки смахиванием (как в панели уведомлений Android)

Tags: android, изображения, sliding

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать следующее: На экран выводятся 4 картинки, необходимо осуществить возможность их удаления смахиванием (наподобие того, как убираются уведомления в панели уведомлений `Android`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте [[@Эдуард Саркисян](/users/12704/%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD)](/users/12704/%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD), я так понимаю реализаций достаточно много.

У меня ссылка есть на вот эту [android-swipetodismiss](https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss)

в вашем случае item это картинка все должно быть просто, если будут вопросы пишите.

Comment: Пытаюсь использовать android-swipetodismiss, но ничего не получается. Пробовал вот так:
imgView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDismissTouchListener(
  imgView,
        null,
        new SwipeDismissTouchListener.OnDismissCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(View view, Object token) {
                dismissableContainer.removeView(imgView);
            }
        }));
    }

Comment: в общем мысли я читать не умею. покажите пожалуйста кусок кода как вы заполняете список или реализацию адаптера и я смогу быстрее вам помочь

Comment: Я не использую listview, адаптер при этом нужен?

Comment: Вообщем разобрался, но есть еще один вопрос. Не пойму как переделать свайп, чтобы картинка смахивалась движением вверх вниз, а не лево право..

Comment: Откройте, пожалуйста, отдельный вопрос для смахивания вверх-вниз. Здесь такой формат - так принято :) . И, если не сложно, напишите вкратце, в чём была проблема (комментарием к вопросу или ответом)